# Database table updation did not work ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update the table (bill) ,field (checked ) , if the user check the checkbox
the field (checked ) will be **1**

**page1 : detail.php**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
   $ch=$row['checked'] ;
   $idw=$row['key'];
}
```

then I check if the user has checked this row before or not if not,I send key&checked in a form to do the check process:

```
if ($ch==1)
{
   echo "this record has been checked";
}
else 
{
   echo "<form action=\"checked.php\" method=\"GET\"  enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"     >";
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ids\" value=\"$idw\" ><br>";
   echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check\" value=\"checked\" ><br>";
   echo "<p><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"  /></p>";
   echo "</form>";
}
```

**page2 : checked.php**

```
$idw=$_GET['ids'];
$check=$_GET['check'];
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 where key=$idw";
$results=mysql_query($sql);
if ($results)
{
     echo "the record has been updated successfully";
}
```

the updation did not work any more , any help please

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Note that this code is really insecure. To avoid sql injection you should at leat use: `$idw= (int) $_GET['ids'];`, at least if the GET should contain a single int value.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your query try, changing this:

```
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 key=$idw";
```

with this:

```
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 WHERE key=$idw";
```

Comment: the (where ) was in code , but I removed it when I was writing the question,

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement should be:

```
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 where key=$idw";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if it do the job for you

```
  WHERE key='".$idw."'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semicolon in your SQL statement in this query:

```
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 where key=$idw;";
               // Notice this semicolon here -^
```

Also, if `key` is  a non-numeric column, you need to put quotes around `$idw`:

```
$sql="UPDATE bill SET checked=1 where key='$idw';";
```

Comment: key is the primary key , int type

Comment: do you thin I should convert $idw to int ?

Comment: No. That's not what I said. I said, if it is not numeric, you need to quote the string.

Answer (score 0):

I put a feild (num) instead of (key "P.K"), then the update done .
But I still don't now why the updating did not happen depending on the P.K

Thank you all.